# WCAT #Requests more than #Virtual Clients

Tags: post, wcat

This problem is now solved.
Removing the content because, I had added too much confidential details earlier.
Thanks stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, WCAT will simulate 1000 virtual clients hammering the site over a duration of 120 seconds.  The 2046 requests are the number of requests completed in that time frame, some of your virtual clients will probably have hit the site multiple times during that time window.

WCAT will give you a number of request served over a period of time.

jMeter on the other hand will perform a pre-defined number of requests and give you a total time to complete them.

Answer (score 0):

Where it is reflected 2625 POSTs? I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Because transactions are being executed in the warm up phase of the load test.

See the highlighted portion below. The text is taken from [GALIN ILIEV'S post on the topic](http://www.galcho.com/articles/StressTestingWCAT.aspx)

> WCAT uses a “warm-up” period in order to allow the Web Server to
>   achieve steady state before taking measurements of throughput,
>   response time and performance counters. For instance there is a slight
>   delay on first request on ASP.NET sites when Just-In-Time (JIT)
>   compilation is performed.
>
> WCAT will divide the warm-up phase into two parts. **For the first
>   half of the warm-up period WCAT will slowly add virtual clients until
>   all virtual clients have been activated.** The second half is pure
>   load generation.